# Can't get a Allure report to be generated in c# specflow .net Core. Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key') Value cannot be null. OnScenarioStart();

Tags: c#, specflow, allure, specrun

I have written a C# test automation Framework on .netcore 3.1 that is using Specflow and Specrun.

I can run the tests with Specrun and get a report, however I would like to get an Allure report.

So I have installed Specflow.Allure. I have an allureConfig.json.

I was hoping that I could now just run the tests and get an Allure report.

However it seems it is not that simple.

When I try to run the tests if fails with the message shown below.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong? Do I need to add more code in order to get the Allure report?

Message: 
    Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key')
  Stack Trace: 
    System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key')
    ConcurrentDictionary`2.ThrowKeyNullException()
    ConcurrentDictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)
    ConcurrentDictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
    AllureStorage.Get[T](String uuid)
    AllureLifecycle.UpdateFixture(String uuid, Action`1 update)
    AllureLifecycle.UpdateFixture(Action`1 update)
    AllureLifecycle.StopFixture(Action`1 beforeStop)
    AllureBindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration)
    TestExecutionEngine.InvokeHook(IBindingInvoker invoker, IHookBinding hookBinding, HookType hookType) line 352
    RunnerTestExecutionEngine.InvokeHook(IBindingInvoker invoker, IHookBinding hookBinding, HookType hookType)
    TestExecutionEngine.FireEvents(HookType hookType) line 338
    TestExecutionEngine.FireScenarioEvents(HookType bindingEvent) line 322
    RunnerTestExecutionEngine.FireScenarioEvents(HookType bindingEvent)
    TestExecutionEngine.OnScenarioStart() line 199
    RunnerTestExecutionEngine.OnScenarioStart()
    TestRunner.OnScenarioStart() line 55
    LM01InitialCaseFeature.ScenarioStart()
    LM01InitialCaseFeature.LM01_01DefaultLM01InitialCase() line 4
    StaticOrInstanceMethodExecutor.ExecuteInternal(ITestThreadExecutionContext testThreadExecutionContext)
    StaticOrInstanceMethodExecutor.Execute(ITestThreadExecutionContext testThreadExecutionContext)
    TestNodeTask.Execute()

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this was to add specflow.json file and set to 'copy if newer' so it copies to the debug folder.

The content of specflow.json was:

```
{
  "stepAssemblies": [
    {
      "assembly": "Allure.SpecFlowPlugin"
    }
  ]
}
```

After making this change the tests ran correctly and an Allure report was generated.